# Can I run two DVI screens from one Thunderbolt 3 port?

Tags: thunderbolt

I'm planning on buying the MacBook pro 2016. I can get it with two or four Thunderbolt 3 ports. However, I want to run two DVI screens with it, and I need one port for charging, and some extra I/O ports would be nice.

I've seen the following online:

[image]

but these only have one DVI port per Thunderbolt 3 port. Is there any way to power two displays like this from one port?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. Here is what you can do:

1. Buy the [CalDigit Thunderbolt™ Station 2](http://www.caldigit.com/thunderbolt-2-dock-TS2/index.asp) (Updated [CalDigit TS3 Lite Thunderbolt 3 Docking Station](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01N5WGDCQ/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_ZHy5ybC5VHZD2))
2. Buy a simple HDMI --> DVI [adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014I8V0EO)
3. Buy a Thunderbolt --> DVI [adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007KB0EGC)

Now, using one Thunderbolt port, you have added two monitors. The Thunderbolt Station includes a Thunderbolt Port, a HDMI port, and plenty of other things the new Macs dropped *(Cough Cough, USB ports)*.

Comment: Equally I could use two Thunderbolt to DVI adaptors? Both those ports can power a display right?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, may have misinterpreted your question. I thought you wanted to power everything through one port since you were looking to get a Mac with two thunderbolt ports.

Comment: I believe even the station doesn't back power? Or not enough to power the MacBook sufficiently... the main concern is just being able to have 2 displays - I wondered if it could be done from one port. The answer is yes - but it's not especially economical!

Answer (score 0):

The [first answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/278773/101825) (go upvote!) put me on the right track.

I think I will buy the newer version of the thunderbolt station - which has 2x Thunderbolt 3 ports:

[CalDigit TS3 Lite Thunderbolt 3 Docking Station](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01N5WGDCQ/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_ZHy5ybC5VHZD2)

And then one of the [USB-C to DVI adaptors](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01MU2WQWD/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_.Fy5ybMJDHAYY)

And one [DisplayPort to DVI adapter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00ZMUL6SI/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_ENy5ybM5ZF9FK)

However, the station is very expensive. I might just get the 4 port MacBook Pro and plug in two USB-C to DVI adaptors. The upgrade is £300 - so £100 more than the station, and you get all the benefits of 4 ports, Touch ID and the Touch Bar. It makes "docking" harder but has significant other benefits.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)